# LibreOffice Calc problem loading large files

Tags: libreoffice, performance

Calc stops responding when opening ~30mb .xlsx 
My task is to open the .xlsx and export it as a csv.

Is there a way (on Ubuntu) limit the number of rows that are loaded into memory?

After attempting 10 times, I got the file open, but it took 5-10 minutes minutes. The file contains ~150.000 rows and 10-20 columns each, on 5 sheets. (no images, pure text). Similar files open slowly with Calc but will eventually open.

My pc has 16BG ram and i7 cpu, so I doubt it is a hardware issue. 
This problem does not happen with MS Office Excel, but Excel has other problems, so I can't use it.

*Note: After opening the file, Calc uses 650mb ram, and the total capacity is* at 25%.

Comment: See if you can pick up some tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-with-command-line

Answer (score -1):

save file as .ods and open it. worked for me.
follow this link to save your excel files.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-excel-to-open-or-save-a-worksheet-in-the-opendocument-spreadsheet-ods-format-c7114baa-f08a-49eb-aefd-f5d61ed347cd